# VIDEOJS player with videojs-contrib-ads Error with m3u8 hls live streaming

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

i use videojs player for watch streaming hls file, and with video-contrib-ads for add adv video for preroll. i get `VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'suppressedTracks') at restorePlayerSnapshot (videojs.ads.js:1417:43)`

with different test:

- videojs with live streaming flux hls m3u8, and without plugin work.
- videojs with video-contrib-ads, with static video or static bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8 work
- videojs with video-contrib-ads with live streaming flux hls m3u8 not work (suppressedTracks error)
- videojs on apple mobile devices not work, only without plugin.

with liveCuePoints bypass error and jump directly to streaming, without show adv:

```
player.ads({
  liveCuePoints: false
});
```

code:

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-ads/6.9.0/videojs.ads.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <video-js id="my_video_1" class=" vjs-default-skin video-js vjs-fluid " controls preload="auto" poster="https://www.lignanosabbiadoro.com/images/webcam3.jpg" >
         <source src="https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      </video-js>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-ads/6.9.0/videojs.ads.js"></script>
      <script>
         videojs('my_video_1', {
         fluid: true
         }, function(){
         var player = this;
         player.ads({debug:true});
         // request ads whenever there's new video content
         player.on('contentchanged', function() {
         // in a real plugin, you might fetch new ad inventory here
         player.trigger('adsready');
         });    
         player.on('readyforpreroll', function() {
         player.ads.startLinearAdMode();
         // play your linear ad content
         // in this example, we use a static mp4
         player.src('images/adv.mp4');
         
         // send event when ad is playing to remove loading spinner
         player.one('adplaying', function() {
          player.trigger('ads-ad-started');
         });
         
         // resume content when all your linear ads have finished
         player.one('adended', function() {
         
          player.ads.endLinearAdMode();
         });
         });
         player.trigger('adsready');
         }); 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```